Firebase Cloud Storage error xhr2 : Unsupported send() data [object Blob]
I use Firebase Cloud Storage with React-Native and I'm trying to upload a byte array in using test function (with Jest), but when I execute uploadBytes I've got an error:

Unsupported send() data [object Blob]

My code:
// Test upload file
test('Upload d un fichier', async () => {
   const storage = getStorage();
   const storageRef = ref(storage, 'some-child');
   
   const bytes = new Uint8Array([0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21]);
   uploadBytes(storageRef, bytes).then((snapshot) => {
     console.log('Uploaded an array!');
   });
})

In details:

C:\Users\FLORIAND\Documents\Humanity\Humanity\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:815
throw new Error(`Unsupported send() data ${data}`);
          ^

Error: Unsupported send() data [object Blob]
at XMLHttpRequestUpload._setData (C:\Users\FLORIAND\Documents\Humanity\Humanity\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:815:17)
at XMLHttpRequest._sendHttp (C:\Users\FLORIAND\Documents\Humanity\Humanity\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:304:23)
at XMLHttpRequest.send (C:\Users\FLORIAND\Documents\Humanity\Humanity\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:192:20)
at XhrTextConnection.send (C:\Users\FLORIAND\Documents\Humanity\Humanity\node_modules\@firebase\storage\src\implementation\requests.ts:469:9)
at doTheRequest (C:\Users\FLORIAND\Documents\Humanity\Humanity\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.esm2017.js:639:20)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\FLORIAND\Documents\Humanity\Humanity\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.esm2017.js:394:7)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)


I use xhr2 and I place global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2"); in the head of my file.
Do you have any idea? I'm trying to test with jest my function to upload a byte array. I expect to retrieve my file on Firebase storage.

Hi everyone, may be this message will be useful for another developper. I've solved my issue. Firebase Cloud Storage and React native work well together. Nevertheless I'm trying to test my function with jest. And i'm trying to test my function with a "lazy" way. it seems that I need to mock my function or something like.

--------------------------- SOLUTION -------------------------
Hi Everyone,
I solved my issue definitively !
I add a comment to explain that my issue was related with Jest and not with firebase Cloud Storage SDK or React Native.
Just if you want to test Cloud Storage SDK with jest youe need to mock XMLHttpRequest functions. To do that you need to add these following lines to your jest.steup.js file
window.XMLHttpRequest = jest.fn(() => ({
  abort: jest.fn(),
  addEventListener: jest.fn(),
  dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  error: jest.fn(),
  getResponseHeader: jest.fn(),
  load: jest.fn(),
  loadend: jest.fn(),
  loadstart: jest.fn(),
  onreadystatechange: jest.fn(),
  open: jest.fn(),
  progress: jest.fn(),
  readyState: jest.fn(),
  removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
  response: jest.fn(),
  responseText: jest.fn(),
  responseType: jest.fn(),
  responseURL: jest.fn(),
  responseXML: jest.fn(),
  send: jest.fn(),
  setRequestHeader: jest.fn(),
  status: jest.fn(),
  statusText: jest.fn(),
  timeout: jest.fn(),
  upload: jest.fn(),
  withCredentials: jest.fn(),
}))

I hope that this post will be help someone in the futur.
Have a nice day
